# Running Untrusted Software on Local Network

Tags: network, windows

So I need to run a bit of software on my local network that I just have the .exe for. The caveat is:

- The software needs access to the internet to produce a bunch of files.
- I need to access those files from another computer on the network (they will be large so over the internet doesn't make much sense).
- The exe will run on windows only.
- The developer will also need remote access to the computer to update the exe so I obviously don't want him to be able to access my local network.

Its 99% likely the software is completely fine but there is the 1% chance it isn't so how can I run the software so it has access to the internet but not to any other resource on the network (and can't get itself access) but other machines on the LAN will be able to access files it produces. Right now all I can think of is running it on a seperate internet connection and having it host an FTP.

I was planning on running this on Windows Server 2008 R2 and have the ability to virtualize the computer through VMWare.

Comment: Under what operating system (ok, Windows, but what version, and do you have a license that would allow running Windows in a virtual machine)? Also, your question is unfinish

Comment: Yes I can run windows within a virtual machine and can run any version of windows. For simplicity was going to probably run Win Server 2K8

Answer (score 3):

DMZ the Windows machine and host a SFTP server on it. Apply firewall rules to limit access to the developer (RDP? ssh?) and the resources from the outside, and for incoming SFTP connections from inside your network. You might also need to protect other assets in the DMZ from this machine.

Your question is unfinished and you omit some details about what environment you are in, but my suggestion follows standard procedure for this very common problem.